# Python error 'numpy.float64' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm using `Python3.x`.
The `bricks = []` the data is dataframe single element array which contains number and some negative numbers

```
for delta in data:
    if delta > 0:
        bricks.extend([1] * delta)
    else:
        bricks.extend([-1] * abs(delta))
```

The above code throws error, without affecting the outcome how to correct the code which will run without errors

The error here is:

> bricks.extend([1] * delta) TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object cannot be
>   interpreted as an integer

**Note** :Community, before giving negative numbers, marked as duplicate provide a solution and then mark as you wish.

Comment: tried this as well another error in that way   for delta in int(data):
TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

Comment: This doesn't look like pandas to me, unless you can provide some input and expected output. Basically, a [mcve].

Comment: bricks = dff[dff['bricks'] != 0]['bricks'].values this is passed as data

Comment: That doesn't look very good, as far as good pandas practices goes. Also, I can't understand what you want. Because I don't have your data, and you haven't explained anything. Gosh, and you're defensive about getting downvotes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should try

```
    bricks.extend([1. * delta])
```

Considering that your "delta" is a simple value(numpyFloat or something like that) and you want to extend the list with a list of 1 value.

Comment: There is no point in guessing. I interpret the OP question as  `data = [2, -2, 3]` -> `bricks = [1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1]`. But who knows. He hasn't provided a reproducible example.